# Jquery tab key press when dropdown options selected

Tags: jquery

I am trying to simulate clicking in to an input box and then tabbing/clicking off it once a drop down has had any option selected.

I have 2 drop downs on a page with a quantity box underneath. Then there is a subtotal price. The subtotal price auto calculates based on the selected drop down options. The options in the drop downs have different prices and so when the quantity is entered a subtotal is displayed. However the subtotal currently only re-calculates AFTER a quantity has been entered and then the user clicks away or tabs off the quantity box.

I would like to remove the need for having to re-enter a quantity and clicking off/tabbing each time.

I know this is not right but its all I have to start with. Basically something like if the select is changed, then simulate clicking in to the #qty box and clicking off/tabbing it.

```
jQuery('select.product-custom-option').on('change', function(){
    jQuery('#qty').val().trigger('change');
});
```

Here is my example HTML. So, customer select option from drop down, then enters quantity, clicks off/tabs and prices update...

How to update price when options are selected or 'simulate' click off from quantity box?

```
<select name="options[517]" id="select_517" class="required product-custom-option"  data-selector="options[517]">
<option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
<option value="3137" price="1.50">Option 1</option>
<option value="3138" price="1.45">Option 2</option>
</select>

<input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty">

<div class="price-box" id="subtotalprice-27107">
<span class="price-container">
<span id="subtotal-excluding-tax-product-price-27107" class="price-excluding-tax">
<span class="price">£15.91</span>
</span>
<span id="subtotal-including-tax-product-price-27107" data-label="Total Inc. VAT" class="price-including-tax" itemprop="price">
<span class="price">£19.09</span>
</span>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your html for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks for looking, I have added some example HTML

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a minimal [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1994081) so we can see what you are trying to do and can easily make changes.

Answer (score 0):

The approach to handle this type of situation is to make a function, let's say calculate(), that reads all the values, does the calculation and display the output. This function should be called on change/keyup etc of all elements that can cause a change in calculation. Using the html provided in question here is how it will work.

```js
$(function() {
  //attach an handler to call 'calculate' on every element that effects the calculations
  $('#qty').on('change', calculate);
  $('#select_517').on('change', calculate);
});


function calculate() {

  //collect values from all elements that effects the calculation
  let opt = $('#select_517 option:selected').data('price');
  let qty = $('#qty').val();

  //do the calcuulations
  let subtotal = opt * qty;
  let total = subtotal + (subtotal * .10); //10% tax

  //display the output
  $('.price-excluding-tax .price').html('£' + subtotal);
  $('.price-including-tax .price').html('£' + total);
}
```

```css
.price-box {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.price-excluding-tax,
.price-including-tax {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="options[517]" id="select_517" class="required product-custom-option" data-selector="options[517]">
  <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
  <option value="3137" data-price="1.50">Option 1</option>
  <option value="3138" data-price="1.45">Option 2</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty">

<div class="price-box" id="subtotalprice-27107">
  <span class="price-container">
<span id="subtotal-excluding-tax-product-price-27107" class="price-excluding-tax">SubTotal: 
<span class="price">£00.00</span>
  </span>
  <span id="subtotal-including-tax-product-price-27107" data-label="Total Inc. VAT" class="price-including-tax" itemprop="price">Total: 
<span class="price">£00.00</span>
  </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately I dont have access to the core code of the function so I am unable to change that. All I can do is workaround my problem at the moment. I can sort of 'half' do it with this, but the subtotal does not change unless you click anywhere on the page. Could it focus on the input then simulate a 'tab' key press?...

`$('.product-custom-option').change(function () {`

    `$('input.qty').focus();`

`});`

Answer (score 0):

I've sorted my problem thanks for looking

```
$('.product-custom-option').change(function () {
    $('input.qty').focus();
    $('input.qty').trigger('blur');
});
```